# ng Repeat with 2 array with one relation between them

Tags: angularjs, arrays, web-services

calling a 2 webservice into an array, which are

1. post webservice
2. comment webservice

suppose i have 2 post and each post are having 3 and 2 comment respectively.

each comment is having post id

example:
Post Array:
[object1,object2]-- here post are coming in object which is having data in

```
{"_identifier":"","_entityName":"CRM_Posts","$ref":"CRM_Posts\/FE8B8DEDBC874F61BA255395C1A07BEE","id":"FE8B8DEDBC874F61BA255395C1A07BEE","liveTransfer":null,"client":"7F3CD06A9B334C5FBED095907D8837A8","client$_identifier":"Ocala\/Fasho Group","organization":"0","organization$_identifier":"*","active":true,"creationDate":"2016-09-24T15:19:37+05:30","createdBy":"436703728E15455D80ED1319C5C7BE9F","createdBy$_identifier":"Tayyab Sayyad","updated":"2016-09-24T15:19:37+05:30","updatedBy":"436703728E15455D80ED1319C5C7BE9F","updatedBy$_identifier":"Tayyab Sayyad","message":"What About This Shipment !","userContact":"9F3332D3D9AA401EACA3AC3B4C684D7F","userContact$_identifier":"Ocala","table":"147718EA960A4BCDBEE9C172E6D7048F","table$_identifier":"OCA_Shippingorder","recordID":"1B3A9D1FDAC84E169060DC2CA216BE76","recordTime":1475492220402}
```

similarly for comment 
array0[object1,object2],
array1[object1,object2,object3]

now i need to iterate it such a way that

example:

Post2 :
     comment1
     comment2
     comment3
post1 :
     comment1
     comment2

i hope i clearly explain my objective and need an reference to implement this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could nest the repeats:

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
{{ post.field }}
    <div ng-repeat="comment in getComments(post.id)">
    {{ comment.field }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Then use functions to filter what your web services return:

```
$scope.getComments = function(postId) {
    return $scope.posts.filter(function(x) { return x.postId == postId; });
};
```